# Converting a string of 1's and 0's to a byte array

Tags: python

I have a string with a length that is a multiple of 8 that contains only 0's and 1's.  I want to convert the string into a byte array suitable for writing to a file.  For instance, if I have the string "0010011010011101", I want to get the byte array [0x26, 0x9d], which, when written to file, will give 0x269d as the binary (raw) contents.

How can I do this in Python?

Comment: [0x26, 0x9d] isn't actually an array of bytes.  It's a list of 2 integers (which are, internally, 4-byte signed values).  Do you mean actual bytes or do you mean integers?  Please clarify your question.

Comment: How should I write the desired result as a byte array and not an int array?

Comment: A sequence of bytes could be a string ('&\x9d') or it could be an actual array (array.array('B',[0x26, 0x9d])).  Many people say "array" when they mean list, tuple or some other sequence (like string).  Or they could mean "array", which is a separate library.

Comment: Sorry.  I've been coding Python for two days, so I haven't caught on to its terminology yet.  What I want is something that, when written to a file, will give a file with the binary content of 0x269d.

Comment: See my response. You need to write a string to the file; writing arrays is not supported.

Comment: Got it.  The phrase "the byte array [0x26, 0x9d]" contradicts "when written to file will give...".  You've over-specified -- saying two things.  Just say what you wont in order to avoid confusion.

Comment: I don't know if I know how to phrase this correctly, so I've made it Community Wiki so that you can have a go at it, S.Lott

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
py> data = "0010011010011101"
py> data = [data[8*i:8*(i+1)] for i in range(len(data)/8)]
py> data
['00100110', '10011101']
py> data = [int(i, 2) for i in data]
py> data
[38, 157]
py> data = ''.join(chr(i) for i in data)
py> data
'&\x9d'
```

Comment: int('0010011010011101', 2) alone is probably sufficient for what the OP wants

Answer (score 6):

You could do something like this:

```
>>> s = "0010011010011101"
>>> [int(s[x:x+8], 2) for x in range(0, len(s), 8)]
[38, 157]
```

Comment: If I write these integers to a file, will they just use up the byte that is required, or will they take up the full size of an int (4 bytes, I think)?

Answer (score 4):

Your question shows a sequence of integers, but says "array of bytes" and also says "when written to file, will give 0x269d as the binary (raw) contents".   These are three very different things.  I think you've over-specified.  From your various comments it looks like you only want the file output, and the other descriptions were not what you wanted.

If you want a sequence of integers, look at Greg Hewgill's answer.

If you want a sequence of bytes (as in a string) -- which can be written to a file -- look at Martin v. Löwis answer.

If you wanted an array of bytes, you have to do this.

```
import array
intList= [int(s[x:x+8], 2) for x in range(0, len(s), 8)]
byteArray= array.array('B', intList)
```

Comment: The sequence of bytes is what I was looking for.  Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3 and number.to_bytes

With Python 3 you can convert numbers to bytes natively with [number.to_bytes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.to_bytes).  The byte array can be written directly to a file.

```
>>> import math,sys
>>> s='0010011010011101'
>>> int(s,2).to_bytes(math.ceil(len(s)/8),sys.byteorder)
b'\x9d&'
>>> with open('/tmp/blah', 'wb') as f:
...     f.write(int(s,2).to_bytes(math.ceil(len(s)/8),sys.byteorder))
... 
2
>>> quit()
```

### file contents

```
[root@localhost prbs]# od -x /tmp/blah
0000000 269d
0000002
```